# Npm is not working,eventhough it shows version

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

I installed node on my computer without any problem.But every time i try to use npm it throws this same error.I tried different node modules and packages,still throws the same error.
node -v
v9.8.0
npm -v
v6.1.0

> npm install polymer-cli -g
>   npm ERR! code E404
>   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: polymer-cli@latest

I tried uninstalling node too.

Comment: "But every time i try to use npm" What `npm` command are you running exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
npm up npm -g 
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Comment: Nope.Npm is completely not working,i Cant even up or downgrade npm or node

Comment: I would recommend clearing your npm cache and trying again: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache